# Delete my account in B2C tenant for social logged in user

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, user-permissions, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a B2C tenant which is used for social login to the web app, I wanted to check regarding delete my account flow.
How can I invoke it for each user who want to delete their account?
When they click delete, it should delete their entry from B2C tenant.
I tried with Graph API but that requires admin role to do that, I want social users to delete their account.
Can user delete its account from B2C tenant directory?
I found this link but not sure how to implement it or use it.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/delete-my-account

Answer (score 0):

This sample uses a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview).

If you look in the policy, you'll see it inherits from "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions". You can find this file in the [starter pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview#custom-policy-starter-pack).

If you haven't set up the custom policy framework, this [utility](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/Experimental?sampleFolderName=delete-my-account) will help.

Comment: So, I have custom policy setup for login flow using something similar to starter pack but I wanted to invoke delete file on delete click, is it possible ? and if yes do you have any example of it ? Thanks.

Comment: No - you can't delete files.

Comment: So, I have a deleteMyAccount policy file, which I want to invoke. I was able to invoke that, but it pops up login box again which asks to login and then I can delete those account with which I log in.